# R: Extract column names conditionally based on column content

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
structure(list(id = 1:10, emrA = c("I219V, T286A", "1", "0", 
"I219V", "I219V", "R164H, I219V", "R164H, I219V", "R164H, I219V", 
"R164H, I219V", "R164H, I219V"), gyrA_8 = c("S83L,678E", "D87N", 
"S83L,252G", "S83L,678E", "S83L,678E", "S83L,828T", "S83L,828T", 
"S83L,828T", "S83L,828T", "S83L,828T"), emrY = c("0", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), T_CIP = c(0.25, 0.12, 0.12, 
0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 2, 1, 1, 2)), .Names = c("id", "emrA", "gyrA_8", 
"emrY", "T_CIP"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Which looks like this:

```
     id emrA         gyrA_8    emrY  T_CIP
      1 I219V, T286A S83L,678E 0     0.25
      2 1            D87N      1     0.12
      3 0            S83L,252G 1     0.12
      4 I219V        S83L,678E 1     0.25
      5 I219V        S83L,678E 1     0.25
      6 R164H, I219V S83L,828T 1     0.5
      7 R164H, I219V S83L,828T 1     2
      8 R164H, I219V S83L,828T 1     1
      9 R164H, I219V S83L,828T 1     1
     10 R164H, I219V S83L,828T 1     2
```

I want to create a vector with the names of the columns which does NOT contain ONLY 1/0.

What I want to get:

```
vector: c("id", "emrA", "gyrA_8", "T_CIP")
```

I have tried to use something like this without luck:

```
lapply(df, function(x) colnames(which(grepl("regex_pattern", x) == TRUE))
```

Comment: None of your column names contain only 0/1.  Maybe you should update with better sample data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The column emrY contains only 0/1 data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, if `df` is your `dataframe` then:

```
output <- df[,!sapply(df, function(x) all(x %in% c(0,1)))]
```

This will give you those columns of which doesn't contain either 0 or 1 only.

if you want the column names then you can do `names(output)` or `colnames(output)`

Comment: @Haakonkas, Glad it did. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) !all(x %in% c(0, 1)), df)
```